# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Backend\UserPriviledge' not found

Tags: laravel

[image]

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8los.png)

[image]

[this is my model for priviledge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLB8N.png)

[image]

[this is Priviledge controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl5eE.png)

gives error once `UserPriviledge` is called.

Comment: Welcome there. Please post your code, not screenshot

Comment: Welcome to community. Please write your question here instead of screenshots. Also use the built in editor capability to write down code and learn about Markdown

Answer (score 1):

You must import `UserPriviledge` Class before using it.
Please Learn OOP Architechture.

Solution 1 (recomended): Class Declaration in `App\Http\Controllers\Backend`

```
`...
 use App\Models\UserPriviledge;
 class PriviledgeController extends Controller
 {
    ...
    UserPriviledge::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()
    ...
 }`
```

Solution 2:

```
`...
 class PriviledgeController extends Controller
 {
     ...
     App\Models\UserPriviledge::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
     ...
 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

add in controller top of the line (import `UserPriviledge` model in controller)

```
use App\Models\UserPriviledge;
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you miss UserPriviledge in your Controller,

add

```
use App\Models\UserPriviledge;
```

in your Controller

Answer (score 0):

This happend for you are not import your model in controller UserPriviledgeController.

```
use App\Models\UserPriviledge;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing UserPriviledge in `UserPriviledgeController`.
Add

```
use App\Models\UserPriviledge
```

to the `UserPriviledgeController`.

The only place where you don't need is importing is where both classes are under the same namespace.